# How to write a boolean that the frame contains a certain JTable - Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a database and I load the data into several JTables. I want to display a row from the active JTable, what my frame contains. But I don't know how to check if my frame contains the **selected / active** JTable.

This is how far I got:

```
 boolean checkTableInFrame(JTable s) {       
     if (frame.getContentPane() == s) {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: how are you adding the table?

Comment: How can I create basic animation in Java?

Comment: Adding a JTable:
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(values [][], columnNames []); JTable jTable = new JTable(tableModelS);

Answer (score 0):

The `getContentPane()`-Method returns a `Container`, and the [Documentation of the Container class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#isAncestorOf%28java.awt.Component%29) states that there is a function named `isAncestorOf(Component c)` to check wether it is an ancestor of the given Component.

So try:

```
boolean checkTableInFrame(JTable s) {       
    return frame.getContentPane().isAncestorOf(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you.

```
 boolean checkTableInFrame(JTable s) {       
   return frame.equals(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(s));
 }
```